# How to get light sensor value and battery level anytime for android?

Tags: android, battery, sensors

I am writing a program and I am able to get the light sensor value and current battery level, but only the light value changes and when the battery level changes.  Is there a way to get these two values anytime?  Like when a user runs my program, I would like to grab the current values right away instead of having to wait for them to change.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the code to receive the value when it changes, you could store the value in a variable and when on every change just update the variable with a setter method. Then, whenever you need the current value anytime, just call the variable using a getter method.

So if your method looks like this

```
private void monitorBatteryState() {
    BroadcastReceiver battReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", -1);
            int health = intent.getIntExtra("health", -1);
            int level = -1;  // percentage, or -1 for unknown
            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
            }
            setBatteryLevel(rawlevel);  // setter method.
            } 
    }

public void setBatteryLevel(rawlevel) {
  batteryLevel = rawlevel;
}

public int getBatteryLevel() {
  return rawlevel;
}
```

You can have a getter method to return the currentl battery level, `rawlevel`, and you can do the same for the light sensor value.

Comment: that wouldn't work for me and after researching it some i found this out about it:  There is no android.os.SystemProperties in the current SDK. That is a class in the source code for use by the firmware only.

Is there any other way to get the light sensor value and the battery level without waiting for it to change?

Comment: I updated my answer, it's an alternative approach if there is no *direct* way to return the value at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your mainActivity:
this is for the light sensor value only because I see someone else has posted about the battery level.

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mLight = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
//don't know if you can put lightSensorValue here, if not try adding it as a member field
final int lightSensorValue;

mSensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener()
{
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
    {
        //do something when accuracy is changed, you probably don't need this
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        lightSensorValue = event.values[0];
    }

}, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

EDIT: i read your question again and see that you want to get it manually anytime. Well this value gets updated whenever the value is changed, so you are always getting the most recent information.

You can try setting changing the delay to `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` and the refresh rate will be a lot faster.